# Why does adress-of operator work in scanf?

Tags: c, scanf, pass-by-reference

```
int a = 5;
int *ptr_a = &a;
```

If I change the `ptr_a` pointer with normal assignment, i.e. `ptr_a = 6`, it will change the `ptr_a` address it points to.

But why does it work on `scanf`?

```
scanf("enter a value", &a);
```

My logic is that since `&a == ptr_a`, any assignment to `&a` will behave like we assign any number to `ptr_a`.

So, can someone explain why assign to `&var` in `scanf` work?

Comment: You don't assign anything to a, your scanf format string don't have any input specified.

Comment: Please provide a [mre], which includes a function `main` as well as all `#include` directives. Please also specify the output of the program. Then we can tell you exactly what is going on in your program.

Comment: `&a` is pointer to `a`. `ptr_a` is a pointer to somewhere, possibly to `a` (like in your code). It is not possible to get to `ptr_a`  itself via `a` or `&a` in any way, any more than `ptr_a` can be used to somehow magically move `a` to different address.

Comment: The line `scanf("enter a value", &a);` will probably effectively do nothing, because a mismatch will probably occur immediately (unless the user actually enters input starting with an `e`), causing `scanf` to return `0`. Therefore, please explain why you believe that it works. As stated in my previous comment, this can be done best by showing us a [mre] and by showing us the output of the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change an object passed to a function you need to pass it by reference.

In C passing by reference means passing an object indirectly through a pointer to it. So dereferencing the pointer you will get a direct access to the original object and can change it.

In this call of scamf

```
scanf("enter a value", &a);
```

the original object `a` is passed by reference. So the function `scanf` can change the object by dereferencing the passed pointer that points to the original object. It is not the pointer that is changed. It is the variable pointed to by the pointer that is changed.

Consider the following demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f1( int x )
{
    x = 10;
}

void f2( int *px )
{
    *px = 10;
}

int main( void ) 
{
    int a = 0;

    printf( "Before calling f1 a = %d\n", a );
    f1( a );
    printf( "After  calling f1 a = %d\n", a );

    putchar( '\n' );

    printf( "Before calling f2 a = %d\n", a );
    f2( &a );
    printf( "After  calling f2 a = %d\n", a );
}
```

.
The program output is

```
Before calling f1 a = 0
After  calling f1 a = 0

Before calling f2 a = 0
After  calling f2 a = 10
```

The function `f1` deals with `a` copy of the value of the original variable `a` because it is passed by value.

The function `f2` has `a` direct access to the original variable a by dereferencing the parameter of the pointer type because the variable `a` is passed by reference.

Comment: By the answer, can I safely assume that scanf internally deference the pointer? (i.e., *&a = value). If so, why direct assignment such as to ptr_a doesnt do the same?

Comment: @TerraGreen The function dereferences the pointer and sets a value to the original object passed through the pointer.  So its look like *ptr_a = value;

Comment: I think I get it now that automatic deference only happen in a function.

Comment: @TerraGreen You are right.:)

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is that in your first example you can also do

```
*ptr_a = 6;
```

which will change the value of `a` itself and not the address `ptr_a` points to.

In the same way, passing `&a` to a function allows that function to change the value of `a`.

Answer (score 0):

The `scanf()` function doesn't change the pointer; it takes the inputted value and stores it at the memory address the pointer points to. The pointer (whose value is the address pointed to) remains the same. You can, of course, reassign a value to a pointer (i.e., change the memory address the pointer points to, as opposed to putting a different value at that address) as in your example `ptr_a = 6`, but it's not at all advisable to do that. That creates undefined behaviour, because you don't know what data is stored at memory address 6.